# Python - Pandas Series append for multiple items in an API

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to form a column in a dataframe from data received from an API. I can retrieve the data fine, but when I attempt to pull it out and into a column, it just repeats the first data point from the API, and not the subsequent items.

```
 batch_api_call_url = f'http example'

  data = requests.get(batch_api_call_url).json()

final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(
            pd.Series
            (
            [
                symbol1,
                #data, {'symbol', 'latestPrice', 'marketCap'},
                data[0]['symbol'],
                data[0]['latestPrice'],
                data[0]['marketCap'],
             'N/A'
            ],
            index = my_columns,
            ),
            ignore_index = True,
            )
        print(final_dataframe)
```

This is my current code. symbol1 pulls from a csv file with a list of names for the rest of the data to be columned with. By keeping the lines as `data[0]['x']`I only get the first iteration for the entire form. Result below.

```
1     AAL       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
2     AAP       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
3    AAPL       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
4    ABBV       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
..    ...          ...                   ...                     ...
95   CINF       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
96     CL       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
97    CLX       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
98    CMA       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
99  CMCSA       131.96           39020816522                     N/A
```

The repeated 131.96, and 3902.... numbers I know are because I have [0] in my pull. But if I removed that, I get a TyperError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

I'm thinking that maybe I need to first convert the data request.get into a separate dict, then convert that into an int? But if that's true I have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I thought it would be worth sharing if someone runs into a similar problem to me.

What I found was that when the API is called, all of the sets are under a number (0, 1, 2, etc) and then the information I wanted to pull out was under those 'headings' (lastestPrice, marketCap, etc)

so I set a variable, that when the loop ran, would increase by one, and then input that variable as the first selector for the series to pull data from.

```
number = 0


    final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(
        pd.Series
        (
        [
            symbol1,
            data1[number]['latestPrice'],
            data1[number]['marketCap'],
        
        ],
        index = my_columns,
        ),
        ignore_index = True,
        )
    print(final_dataframe)
    number = number + 1
```

This resolved my issue, and I hope it helps someone else! I know it's not super technical, but I struggled with the language on the other questions as a beginner myself. :)